# How do you call java code in Apache ODE using BPEL

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, eclipse-plugin, bpel

I have implemented HelloWorld in a BPEL project and successfully run it.
As the next step, I want to run some java code through Apache ODE using BPEL.

Comment: You mean you want to call a Java program from ODE? In that case, your Java program needs a Web Service interface through which it can be called.

Comment: @joergl : please give an example, i am a newbie..

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials available on the net, try using a search engine. Hint: You are looking for an example of an `invoke` activity. Try something and if you have problems come back with concrete code on which you are stuck.

Comment: I tried to use invoke in Apache ODE, I want to create a file .

Comment: http://www-inf.int-evry.fr/cours/WebServices/TP_BPEL/ifelse.html
while following the above link i tried to just display an input string which is entered,similarly will it be possible to invoke a java  code or create a text file ??

Comment: There are no file handling mechanisms in BPEL. All you can do is invoke Web Services and that of course includes Web Services implemented in Java. Here is a [hello world tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example-document-style/) for JAX-WS, a Java spec for building Web Services. You need to implement such a service (that creates a text file or does whatever you want) and then you can point a BPEL process to it and invoke the service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Java embedding in the Orchestration process, Java Embedding component is available in the BPEL components.

Comment: No, Java Embedding is not part of the BPEL standard and Apache ODE (which is the subject of the question) does not support such an activity)